# Admob banner hidden

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I was able to put together the code from Libgdx and Google play to add Ads from adMob but I cannot seem to bring the banner on top of the game screen and the banner only shows once I hit the back bottom and exit the app.

My code is below
any help would be appreciated

Android main class

```
  public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {

   static AdView adView;


    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "my id";
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    //cfg.useGL20 = false;
    //initialize(new GameActivity(), false);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);


    View gameView = initializeForView(new GameActivity(), true);



      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

        .addTestDevice("my device")
        .build();
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gameParams.bottomMargin = 1;
     layout.addView(gameView, gameParams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    setContentView(layout);

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
     if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }

    super.onDestroy();
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
     if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }

    super.onPause();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (adView != null) {
          adView.resume();
        }
    super.onResume();
}
  }
```

Comment: try using different AdSize, like `AdSize.SMART_BANNER`

Comment: the issue is not the size but the banner is hidden behind the game screen (Splash, and any other screen in the game) I need to bring the banner view to the front

Answer (score 0):

Solved see Edited code, added LayoutParams to the game view

Answer (score -2):

I found it: 
I just had to change

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_BANNER);
```

to

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
```

Comment: It is rather risky to post your mail address publicly. Makes it too easy for spam bots to pick it up.